# invalid command line parameter when android execution

Tags: android-emulator

When I click the run as android application it shows the following error:

```
[2011-05-20 10:32:45 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: on.
[2011-05-20 10:32:45 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2011-05-20 10:32:45 - Emulator] please use -help for more information
```

Comment: Did the emulator environment you're using give you a chance to name your device? Did it perchance start with `on ` or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably due to a space in the path. As Revision 12 is giving this error for everyone. Mine is Revision 12 in Eclipse Indigo Classic.

- Please move your android-sdk folder to somewhere so that there doesn't contain any space in the path.
- Or, try from command line.

Answer (score 0):

Use below steps -

1. Right click Project -> Run As -> Run Configure -> Target
2. Scroll Down
3. Additional emulator command line option, type

   ```
   -http-proxy http://10.1.1.10:8080
   ```
4. Restart ur emulator, it will work, and it is working for me too